# What ways can you counter or avoid being hit by karthus' ult?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Hexdrinker the only item that can counter Karthus' ultimate?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58521/is-hexdrinker-the-only-item-that-can-counter-karthus-ultimate)

Are there ways to counter Karthus' ult or avoid it altogether?