# What can Shaco's ultimate dodge?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was spectating a game and saw a player dodge Ezreal's ultimate with Shaco's ultimate. I was just wondering what other ultimates you could dodge?

Comment: Well, it is just a split second when you dissapear so i would say anything that is a skillshot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty much anything. When you use it, you basically cease to exist for half a second. **During this time, Shaco is completly invulnerable to any damage.** So if you time it *exactly* right, you can even dodge targeted abilities, like Caitlyn's or Darius' ultimate. You also won't take damage from DoTs and persistant AoE attacks durning the duration, but this is less useful, because of the short duration of the effect - you will dodge one tick at most.

For other types of untargetability see: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Untargetable

Comment: Like Karthus ult?

Comment: Yes, see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58521/how-to-counter-karthus-ultimate

Comment: @CetoBlackWeasel Shaco dodging Karthus ult http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8VlyFgbnGw&feature=player_detailpage#t=90s

Comment: Could you expand the answer a bit more based on the information on the wiki page? It also includes what Shaco's ult **can't** dodge and that's useful to know

Comment: @BBz: Actually, no it doesn't. The **other** sources of untargetability can and can't dodge various things. Shaco and Zhonya's give complete untargetability, and the champion is, to quote the wiki, "invulnerable to all damage". The wiki page may cause some confusion at first, but when you look closely, you can see that it's formatted: Type, Description, Examples. Shaco is and example of the first type, so only the description directly above applies to him.

Comment: @Delf So if Shaco's ignited and then he ults, he could potentially skip a tick on the ignite?

Comment: @BBz: Yes. I've just expanded the answer to add that. :)

Comment: Also good for dodging skillshots if you've got quick reactions.